# Oracle SQL-Developer: Export "Explain Plan" Images?

Tags: oracle, image, sql-execution-plan

I'm trying to export a copy of the Explain Plan from Oracle SQL Developer 2.1.0.63

All I get out is a html file named what I specify, then a newly created folder in the same directory called "images", which is empty.

I've taken a squizz at the (cough)tabular(cough) HTML output, found there's half a dozen images specified, but I think there's CSS (style not specified inline, CSS not imported though) and Javascript (expand/contract areas) that I'm missing as well.

I've tried googling the names of the images that are most unique, but I can't find any other resource with this issue.

Is there a location online I can get these images/CSS/Javascript, OR is this a bug AND there is a fix somewhere OR am I just a noob?

The machine I'm using SQL Developer on has full admin rights, so it shouldn't be an issue of lack of create rights, especially in my own desktop/my documents UNLESS there's another place the images are stored in. I'm searching my HDD now, to see if I can find them anywhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the SQL Developer directory, there is a file `oracle.sqldeveloper.worksheet.jar`
Open that with IZArc (or WinZip or some equivalent) and under `oracle/dbtools/worksheet/images`
 you'll find the ones you'll need.

Comment: You, sir, are a Oracle god among men.

Comment: As of version 3.0.04 (Oct 2011), it seems like SQL Developer generates an images directory in the same dir as the html file now - at least on Mac

Answer (score 1):

I used the print-command, and printed to a PDF-Printer. That gave me exactly the whole explain plan output inside a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating an explain plan using plain old SQL?

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211.pdf

Comment: The output I'm getting is an explain plan anyway, just with HTML wrappers. I wanted to get the program's functionality working, because it is easier to understand for the business.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently hit this issue and created a small batch script (requires sed) to insert all required images directly into export plan html file as css resources. So you can share your plan and receiver will see normal images, not "broken image" icons.

https://anilech.blogspot.com/2016/05/how-to-keep-images-inside-oracle-sql.html

<sub>I know, this is very timely response :)</sub>